# Ember.js JSONApi, serializers, nested models

Tags: json, serialization, ember.js, deserialization

How could I serialize just created model with just created related models? 
Example:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

//model "list"
export default DS.Model.extend( {
  contacts: DS.hasMany('contact')
});

//model "contact"
export default DS.Model.extend( {
  numbers: DS.hasMany('phone-number'),
  list: DS.belongsTo('list')
});

//model "phone-number"
export default DS.Model.extend( {
  numbers: DS.belongsTo('contact')
});
```

When a user creates new list with phone numbers I'd like to get whole information threw the list.serialize() method and next parse it on server side (rails), what is the right way to do that?

Ember 2.3
Ember-data 2.3
JsonApi

Comment: Hi @costa did you find the solution for your problem? What serializer in the server side are you using? I have a similar problem trying to find more information about how works the creation of resources with nested/related resources with AMS 10.rc4 + Ember Data 2.3 using JSON API. Please if you have some feedback it would be a great help! Thanks

Comment: @hernanvicente Hello! I made it by myself, but it's not completely finished, if u are interested I can share the code on the GitHub in the morning  and we could discuss it.